# Examples of Pseudo-adjunctions

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, 2-categories

Let $K$ and $L$ be strict $2$-categories. A pseudo-adjunction consists of two pseudo-functors $F: K \to L$ and $U: L \to K$ together with a pseudo-natural equivalence $\phi_{X,Y}: L(FX,Y) \simeq K(X,UY)$. [Equivalently](https://www.brics.dk/NS/98/7/), a pseudo-functor $U$ has a left pseudo-adjoint $F$ if and only if there are objects $FX$ in $L$ together with universal $1$-cells $\eta_X: X \to UFX$. Universal means that the functor $\eta_X^*  U: L(FX,Y) \to K(X,UY)$ is an equivalence for each $Y$.

Texts about 2-categories feature surprisingly little concrete examples. I'd like to see some example of pseudo 2-adjoints, so if you know some please tell me. :) I am especially interested in examples which are connected to programming language semantic/categorical logic/type theory.

What I already know from John Power's text is that the strict forgetful 2-functor $\mathcal{CCCat}_g \to \mathcal{Cat}_g$ from the 2-category of cartesian closed categories, functors which preserve the structure up to canonical isomorphisms and invertible (!) natural transformations to the 2-category of categories, functors and invertible transformations has a pseudo-left adjoint. I guess the $FX$ can be constructed using some variation of the $\lambda$-calculus. Can $F$ be turned into a strict 2-functor?

I also believe that there is a pseudo-left adjoint to the forgetful 2-functor $\mathcal{Lex} \to \mathcal{Cat}$ from the 2-category of finitely complete categories, left-exact functors and natural transfomations. Similar for categories with finite products.

Comment: Many 2-categories of categories with structure (eg. complete or monoidal) arise as 2-categories of algebras, pseudomorphisms and transformations for a 2-monad on $\mathsf{Cat}$. The forgetful 2-functor will be strict, but has a pseudo-left-adjoint.

Comment: Also the inclusion of the 2-category of algebras, strict morphisms and transformations embedds into the 2-category with pseudomorphisms by means of a canonical strict 2-functor, which has a pseudo-left adjoint.

Comment: @JonasLinssen Thx. Is this true for elementary topoi? Why can't we make the left adjoint strict?

Comment: Actually I think I was wrong in both cases, because I didn’t check my notes. The left adjoints are strict, but in the first case the adjunction is just up to Hom-wise equivalence as opposed to Hom-wise iso…

Comment: Anyway one example I am sure of: If you consider conical weak 2-limits in a (strict or weak) 2-category, if the latter has all of them they are given by a pseudofunctor defining a pseudo-left adjoint to the diagonal.

Comment: @Jonas Linssen Can I read your notes too? Or are they handwritten?

Comment: They are private notes on paper of a lecture on 2-monad theory held by Dr. Daniel Schäppi, which unfortunately I have not yet digitalized. A good start for this business is Lack‘s A 2-category companion, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Yes. I have Lack's notes, but they are omitting a lot of details. The paper on two dimensional monad theory by power, kelly & blackwell is to hard for me at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: @Jonas Linssen Are you sure it is my.name@... or should I insert your name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137251/discussion-between-merle-and-jonas-linssen).